# XSLT stylesheet won't link to XML in browser

Tags: xml, xslt

Newbie here so sorry if this is a basic question, basically I have an XML that won't link to my XSL stylesheet. This is what is at the top of my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TransformDocument.xsl"?>
<root>
  <listing>
    <seller_info>
```

The XSL stylesheet is contained within the same folder and is called TransformDocument.xsl, which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3org1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/listing"/>
    </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="listing">
    Testing123
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not getting testing123 displaying anywhere when I open the XML file. I don't think it is linking because I also just put testing123 in the `<body>` tags and still nothing was displayed.

I have tried this in Chrome and Edge.

I tried this as well but again nothing was displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3org1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                Testing123
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you loading the XML document from the local file system or over HTTP(S)? Browsers don't support the `xml-stylesheet` pseudo pi anymore when loading XML from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers have a security feature that prevents web pages from loading other files from local folders. I'll quickly explain the reasoning behind this "annoying" feature. Then at the end of this answer in the last paragraph, I'll have a solution for you.

Normally each tab in the browser is a separate isolated virtual sandbox, that cannot communicate with the rest of your computer and therefore has no access to your file system. If you had a web page that "somehow" achieved to reload or open a file from your local hard disk, you would have the situation that this web page and one of your own files are in the same sandbox. Both files would be stored in the same piece of RAM. That principally could mean, that the web page has access to your file system, which is a high security risk. For example JavaScript is not considered as a very secure technology. Security gaps could allow a JavaScript program to break out of its own program, so that it gets access to areas of the RAM where it normally should not have access. Instead of making JavaScript secure enough, the browser developers decided for this isolation/sandboxing approach.

In consequence links of the format `file://` will never work in html. There is only one exception. If you open a file manually (with the file open dialog or by typing it into the address bar), what happens is that the web browser reads that file into a pure Ascii text buffer without even looking at it (and therefore not knowing that it needs a stylesheet), creates a fresh sandbox and moves the buffer into the sandbox. Before the rendering process is started, the sandbox is isolated (and also disconnected from your file system). This happens even before the control is passed to the sandbox. Therefore after the rendering process is started there is no access to the file system any more.

If you just use the address `TransformDocument.xsl`, the browser will automatically make a correct link for you. If your have a web page, the browser will add `http://` or `https://` for you. If you have a local file, the browser will add `file://` for you. But then when the file is required in the the rendering process, the sandbox is already isolated.

For debugging purposes in some web browsers this mechanism can temporarily be disabled. For example when you start Chrome from the command line, you can pass the argument `--allow-file-access-from-files`. This gives you the behaviour that you want. But probably you should not use that instance of Chrome for web browsing.